# Trying to left-align text in a centered element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to achieve what you see at the bottom of the panel in the image below. Each of the 3 items are centered but the text is left aligned.

I have developed the following basic CSS and HTML code. I am trying to use flexbox as much as possible for responsive layout. Anyone have any pure HTML/CSS solution?

I understand that the `p` tag is a block level element. So what are my options without setting the width of the `p` tag? Or maybe there is another tag I could use?

The HTML and CSS code I have provided below has the basic structure only.

[image]

```css
.panel {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 300px;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.panel-body {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.panel-heading {
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.panel-body div.chart {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  min-height: 150px;
  background-color: green;
}

.panel-body div {
  text-align: center;
  flex: auto;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

p {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    HEADING
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="chart"></div>
    <div>
      <p>HIGH
        <br/>144</p>
    </div>
    <div>MEDIUM
      <br/>2</div>
    <div>LOW
      <br/>3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see no `<p>` tags within MEDIUM nor LOW.. However, there is one within HIGH and seems to be doing what you're after..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just changed styles of `.panel-body div`. Also there is no need for `p` tag here, consider removing it from markup. Demo:

```css
.panel {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 300px;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.panel-body {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.panel-heading {
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.panel-body div.chart {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  min-height: 150px;
  background-color: green;
}

.panel-body div {
  /* Take 33.33% width, allow grow and shrink */
  flex: 1 1 33.33%;
  background-color: red;
  /* become a flex-container */
  display: flex;
  /* align flex-items vertically */
  flex-direction: column;
  /* center vertically */
  justify-content: center;
  /* center horizontally */
  align-items: center;
}

p {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    HEADING
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="chart"></div>
    <div>
      <p>HIGH
        <br/>144</p>
    </div>
    <div>MEDIUM
      <br/>2</div>
    <div>LOW
      <br/>3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this HTML code:

```
<div class="panel">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    HEADING
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="chart"></div>
    <div><p>HIGH<br/>144</p></div>
    <div><p>MEDIUM<br/>2</p></div>
    <div><p>LOW<br/>3</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It appears that you originally only put the div containing "HIGH" and "144" in a `<p>` tag, which, according to your css code, is the attribute that is being styled to have left-aligned text.  However, the content within the other 2 `<div>`s were not enclosed within a `<p>` tag, and so they were not being styled.